# what does ?? mean in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have recently seen `??` in JS, or maybe it's a Typescript thing. It seems to behave the same as `||`

code looks something like this

```
import GeneralImage from './images'

const Team = ({ teamImg }) => {
   return <img src={teamImg ?? GeneralImage} />
}
```

I would have thought to have done the following, but maybe there is a difference. Cannot find anything online for `??` but the linter doesn't seem bothered and it works the same.

```
const Team = ({ teamImg }) => {
   return <img src={teamImg || GeneralImage} />
}
```

Comment: [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). You didn't have to delete your question...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ah ok. When I try the demo on the man page I see the following `Error: Unexpected token '?'`

Comment: becuase: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Don't use `??`. It has very low support - effectively a FF extension at this point as part of a proposal.

Comment: just saw it's not supported in safari - thanks

Comment: is it a new feature? Just supported for Firefox? @user2864740

Comment: @peterflanagan It's not defined in any published ECMAScript standard, including ES6. Right now, *`??` is a vendor-specific non-standard language extension*. So yes, it's a "feature" of FF that should not be generally used.

Comment: and @PatrickRoberts is it just to cover cases if you consider 0, '', or NaN as valid values?

Comment: @user2864740 — Given this is the year of ES11, it isn't much of a surprise that ES6 doesn't have bleeding edge features :)

Comment: @user2864740 "including ES6"... that seems irrelevant. The only relevant standard in my opinion would be ES2020

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Then tag the question appropriately and add disclaimers. Now, back in the real world, I've some coffee to refill..

Comment: @user2864740 I'm not OP, didn't tag it...

Comment: updated the tag. Tagged it with ES6 as was unsure if it was a new feature that I had missed

Comment: @peterflanagan — It is new. It's just a Stage 4 Proposal which will probably be in ES2020, not part of the ES6 spec from 2015.

Comment: thanks @Quentin The tag has been removed so everyone can rest easy tonight 

Comment: @PatrickRoberts once introduced can you see it been used more often than the more traditional `||`

Comment: @peterflanagan We have null coalesce in PHP and I use it as a switch. Especially if an argument is typed, for instance (`?string $name`), you can do a switch-thru (like fall-through, like Maybe or Optionals) to respond to a non-property: `$fullname = $name ?? $user['name'];` It is not the same, at least in PHP, as a falsey optional, which is `?:` and called a short ternary.

Comment: @Quentin not "probably", [it already is](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-CoalesceExpression)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts do you predict it to be used over `||` once released?

Comment: @peterflanagan asking for opinions is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts whoops, sorry for breaking the rules  where is the best place I can ask you for your opinion? Do you have an email address, or maybe a telephone number I could contact you on?